# Automating iTunes mouse click in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, events, mouse, itunes

I am trying to automate a left mouse click in iTunes from Objective-C. I am doing the following.

1. first I am listening to iTunes events

   ```
   [[NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                    selector:@selector(allDistributedNotifications:)
                                                    name:nil
                                                    object:nil];
   ```
2. when the allDistributedNotifications is called I do the following:

   ```
   - (void) allDistributedNotifications:(NSNotification *)note {
       NSString *object = [note object];
       NSString *name = [note name];
       NSDictionary *userInfo = [note userInfo];
       NSLog(@"object: %@ name: %@ userInfo: %@",object, name, userInfo);

       if([object isEqualToString:@"com.apple.iTunes.dialog"]&& [userInfo objectForKey:@"Showing Dialog"] == 0){
           NSLog(@"*** ended iTunes Dialogue");
       }

       if([name isEqualToString:@"com.apple.iTunes.sourceSaved"]){
           NSLog(@"*** iTunes saved to file");
           currentURLIndex +=1;
           [self loadWithData:[itmsURLs objectAtIndex:currentURLIndex] fromBot:YES];
       }
   }
   ```
3. LoadWithData looks like this

   ```
   -(void) loadWithData:(NSURL*) url fromBot:(BOOL)aBot
   {
       BOOL success;

       success = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURLs:[NSArray arrayWithObject:url]
                 withAppBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.itunes"
                 options:NSWorkspaceLaunchDefault
                 additionalEventParamDescriptor:nil
                 launchIdentifiers:nil];
       if(success){
           [numAppsDownloaded setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:   @"%lu",currentURLIndex+1]];
       }
       if(success && aBot){
           [self performSelector:@selector(clickDownload) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
       }
    }
   ```
4. clickdownload in turn looks like this

   ```
   -(void) clickDownload
   {
       NSPoint mouseLoc;

       mouseLoc                = [NSEvent mouseLocation]; //get current mouse position
       CGPoint point           = CGPointMake(mouseLoc.x, mouseLoc.y);

       CGEventRef theEvent;
       CGEventType type;

       CGMouseButton button    = kCGMouseButtonLeft;

       type                    = kCGEventLeftMouseDown; // kCGEventLeftMouseDown = NX_LMOUSEDOWN,
       theEvent                = CGEventCreateMouseEvent(NULL,type, point, button);

       NSEvent* downEvent      = [NSEvent eventWithCGEvent:theEvent];
       [self forwardEvent:downEvent];

       [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.2];

       type                    = kCGEventLeftMouseUp;
       theEvent                = CGEventCreateMouseEvent(NULL,type, point, button);
       NSEvent* upEvent        = [NSEvent eventWithCGEvent:theEvent];
       [self forwardEvent:upEvent];
   }
   ```

   5.Finally, forwardEvent looks like this

   ```
   - (void)forwardEvent: (NSEvent *)event
   {
       NSLog(@"event: %@",event);

       pid_t PID;
       NSInteger WID;

       // get the iTunes Window ID

       NSArray* windows    =  (NSArray*)CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly | kCGWindowListExcludeDesktopElements, kCGNullWindowID);

       NSEnumerator* windowEnumerator = [windows objectEnumerator];

       while( (window = [windowEnumerator nextObject] ) )
       {
           if([[(NSDictionary*) window objectForKey:@"kCGWindowName"]  isEqualToString:@"iTunes"])
               WID = (NSInteger)[(NSDictionary*) window objectForKey:@"kCGWindowNumber"];
       }

       ProcessSerialNumber psn;
       CGEventRef CGEvent;
       NSEvent *customEvent;

       NSPoint mouseLoc        = [NSEvent mouseLocation]; //get current mouse position
       NSPoint clickpoint      = CGPointMake(mouseLoc.x, mouseLoc.y);

       customEvent = [NSEvent mouseEventWithType: [event type]
                                  location: clickpoint
                             modifierFlags: [event modifierFlags] | NSCommandKeyMask
                                 timestamp: [event timestamp]
                              windowNumber: WID
                                   context: nil
                               eventNumber: 0
                                clickCount: 1
                                  pressure: 0];

       CGEvent = [customEvent CGEvent];

       // get the iTunes PID

       NSRunningApplication* app;

       NSArray* runningApps = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] runningApplications];

       NSEnumerator* appEnumerator = [runningApps objectEnumerator];

       while ((app = [appEnumerator nextObject]))
       {
           if ([[app bundleIdentifier] isEqualToString:@"com.apple.iTunes"])

               PID = [app processIdentifier];
       }
       NSLog(@"found iTunes: %d %@",(int)PID,WID);

       NSAssert(GetProcessForPID(PID, &psn) == noErr, @"GetProcessForPID failed!");

       CGEventPostToPSN(&psn, CGEvent);
   }
   ```

The problem is that I cannot see the mouse click being performed.

Comment: Why are you signing up for all distributed notifications? There are many that have nothing to do with iTunes; your code will be much simpler and your application will run more efficiently if you sign up for the specific iTunes notifications you're interested in by name. Second, your forwardEvent: method appears to ignore the event passed into it, instead creating a new one. Third, you're assuming that the mouse cursor is within the iTunes window, which may be unlikely.

Comment: What's up with the title of this question?

Answer (score 0):

You are sending left mouse button events with `NSCommandKeyMask`. For right click equivalent (i.e. control-click) you would want to use `NSControlKeyMask`. Alternatively you could just use right mouse button events without a modifier mask.

Comment: Hi Nick. I am sending left down and up events ([self forwardEvent:NSLeftMouseDown];[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.2];[self forwardEvent:NSLeftMouseUp];) Am I doing something wrong here? I had tried setting modifierFlags to 0 but it didn't work.

Comment: There are two ways to "right click": (1) press right mouse button, or (2) press left mouse button while holding the **control (⌃)** key. Your code does neither of these, you are pressing the left button while holding the **command (⌘)** key.

Comment: NSCommandKeyMask was wrong. agreed. but i am not trying to right click. I am trying to left click down and then up on a button in itunes. i want to simulate a left button click. thanks Nick

Comment: OK, but your opening sentence is "I am trying to automate a right mouse click"

Comment: oh my bad. Sorry. any suggestions why the code is not working?